# Unreasonably large values of timing of hash functions

Tags: python, hash, timing, timeit

The idea is to compare the timing of two functions calculating hashes: custom function `calculate_hash` and method `calculatehash` provided by `py.path` module.

The helper function `construct_objects` creates dummy objects for calculating hash.

I assume there is some mistake in my timing code, as the results of timing are unreasonably large (even of `calcultehash` method).

```
def construct_objects(directory, test=False):
      """Creates files objects and writes in each of them binary data

      directory: object oriented interface to os.path module

      if test=True - asserts equality between hashes calculated 
                     by calculate_hash function and path.computehash method

      returns iterator of paths as strings of created file objects
      """

      paths = []
      for ind in range(10):
            path = directory.join(str(ind))
            data = bytearray(random.choice([0, 1]) for dummy_ind 
                             in range(100000))
            path.write_binary(data)
            paths.append(path)

      if test:      
            for path in paths:
                  assert path.computehash() == calculate_hash(path)
      paths = map(str, paths)
      return paths

if __name__ == '__main__':
      tmp = py.path.local('/tmp')
      tmp = tmp.mkdtemp()
      paths = list(construct_objects(tmp, test=True))

      setup1 = 'from duplicates import calculate_hash; from __main__ import paths'
      stmt1 = 'for path in paths: calculate_hash(path)'
      timer1 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt1, setup=setup1)
      print(timer1.repeat())

      setup2 = 'import py.path; from __main__ import paths'
      stmt2 = 'for path in paths: py.path.local(path).computehash()'
      timer2 = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt2, setup=setup2)
      print(timer2.repeat())
```

UPDATED:

I followed the advice given by @Peilonrayz and tested the `calculate_hash` function with different sizes of chunks. All test uses the same input - 10 files of 100 kB each, the number of repetitions is 1000, repeat=3

```
Function `calculate_hash` with chunk_size = 524288:
 [3.166437058000156, 3.1616951290016004, 3.1614671890001773]

Function `calculate_hash` with chunk_size = 4098:
 [3.173143865000384, 3.1707858160007163, 3.1684196309997787]

Function `calculate_hash` with chunk_size = md5.blocksize (64): 
[3.17174992100081, 3.1530033399994863, 3.152337475999957]

Method `compute_hash`:  
[4.248858199000097, 4.240910821001307, 4.2475174219998735]
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be wise, sharing the `calculate_hash` function as well?

Comment: @user1767754, You are right, I have added a calculate_hash

Comment: @Peilonrayz, I have updated the question, please, take a look. PS I just finished a research on your answer to my previous question: the way you packed methods of checking the duplicates is very elegant and efficient. Each subsequent method is called only if the previous one didn't obtain the definite result. Took me some time to get it:)